# One BU to multiple BU

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have a Marketing Cloud org that is currently comprised of one BU. We have a project which will require that we now manage multiple BUs in our org but there are quite a few automations/data extensions / content that has been setup at the TOP LEVEL BU (only BU that exists today). Marketing CLoud Connect is not setup yet.

Do we need to create a child BU and move all the Data extensions and Content into new folder structures for the child BU (they don't need to be shared). This will require quite a bit of remediation work. Also, the data in the All Subscribers list will need to be updated so that the data at the top level BU for a subscriber is reflected at the child BU all Subscriber list.

Is there an easier way ? Create a new BU and make that one the parent and leave the current one untouched ?

Comment: Going from single BU to multi BU is not easy. It all comes down to the requirements to data and content separation. One thing is certain - you cannot add a new BU as a parent, only as a child. This is why I always advice new MC implementations to start with two BUs - as this will allow them to build everything brand-specific in the child, while keeping the parent (root) solely as an "umbrella".

Comment: Makes perfect sense @LukasLunow, is there a tool that can migrate some of the data extensions, content , automations, journeys in an automated way from the parent to the newly created child BU ? Sounds like a lot of work transferring all that manually.

Comment: you can use [Deployment Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_deployment_manager.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) to migrate some of it, or reach out to Salesforce to have this done as a billable services engagement - as they have some tools to automate such migrations.